# How to properly change view controllers hierarchy?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Suppose this is my view hierarchy,

View Controllers : L `(login:success)` -> A | B | C | D | E -> `(logout)` L

Yes, this is a `UITabbarController` enabled app, and from any tab user can logout and I'll need to take him out to L. Each tab having separate `UINavigationController`.

From VC

- A user can go to A1 *>* A2 *>* A3
- B user can go to B1 *>* B2 *>* B3
- C user can go to C1 *>* C2 *>* C3
- D user can go to D1 *>* D2 *>* D3 *>* D4
- E user can go to E1 *>* E2

Suppose, user of my app is at following position for particular tab,

- Tab 1 : A3
- Tab 2 : B3
- Tab 3 : C3
- Tab 4 : D3
- Tab 5 : E2

Now,

My questions?

- If a user wants to logout from E2 – How do I take him to L by also removing all pushed view controllers from each tabs?
- Is it needed? If yes, then how do I do that for different navigation controllers.
- Is there any good way available?

What I'm thinking to do?

- I'll simply change root view controller to L but I think this is not a good way to get this done.

**Update : Found this !**

**Before Login :**

[image]

**After Login :**

[image]

**After Logout :**

[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only followed the way – I was thinking of.

I changed root view controller to L after setting nil for `UITabbarController` `viewControllers` property. This will call `dealloc` of those classes. Also, I'm travelling a loop in each of tab to pop it to its root.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reordering the navigation stack why not just show the logout view modally from each navigation controller with `presentViewController`.

If a user wants to logout of E2, present the logout view modally, assign a delegate call back so you know once they've logged out and the view is about to dismiss. Before that happens pop back to root (E1).

Comment: Good point +1 ! But still I'm looking for another solution and answers to my questions.